# why is this code giving segmentation fault

Tags: c

This is the error when dubugging

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. [Switching to
>   Thread 0x7ffff6ff5700 (LWP 17504)] 0x000000000040124c in push
>   (q=0x7ffff6ff4ec0, n=...) at discover.h:27 27
>   q->TailCpuNode->next=temp;

```
    typedef struct CpuNode
        {   
        struct CpuNode *next;
        int cpuid;
        }CpuNode;

        typedef struct List
        {   struct CpuNode *HeadCpuNode;
            struct CpuNode *TailCpuNode;

        }List;

        inline static void push(struct List *q,CpuNode *n){
        struct CpuNode *temp;                       

         temp= (struct CpuNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct CpuNode));
         temp->cpuid=n->cpuid;
         temp->next=NULL;
         if (q->HeadCpuNode==NULL) q->HeadCpuNode=q->TailCpuNode=temp;
         else {
              q->TailCpuNode->next=temp;
              q->TailCpuNode=temp;
            }   
        }

        void Discover(struct List *Acqcores){
         struct CpuNode *temp;
         temp= (CpuNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct CpuNode));
         temp->cpuid=1;
         push(Acqcores,temp);
        }



    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct List Acq_cores;
    Discover(&Acq_cores);
}
```

Comment: Based on that message alone, I'd say either `q` or `q->TailCpuNode` doesn't hold a determinate address. Time to fire up your debugger and start walking the callstack backwards.

Comment: Can you give us enough code to replicate the problem?

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Then use your debugger to narrow down the problem.  Then ask a specific question if you don't understand the results of your debugging efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't initialize `Acq_cores` so you access uninitialized variables. That is undefined behavior and may cause a crash.

Try:

```
struct List Acq_cores = {NULL, NULL};
```

Besides that you have memory leaks. Change to this:

```
    void Discover(struct List *Acqcores){
     struct CpuNode *temp;
     temp= (CpuNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct CpuNode));
     temp->cpuid=1;
     push(Acqcores,temp);
     free(temp);            // Add this
    }
```

In general you would do better with:

```
    void Discover(struct List *Acqcores){
     struct CpuNode temp;
     temp.cpuid=1;
     push(Acqcores,&temp);
    }
```

See demo here http://ideone.com/rIYknh

Comment: Its working after Initialization of struct but I do not understand, mean I used to use uninitialized structs but I never got this

Comment: see this [http://ideone.com/MgHycX] I haven't initialized struct but it is still working

Comment: @jayasimhasai - your link does not work so I can't see your code. Notice: Uninitialized structs declared inside a function is bad (it may work, it may fail). Global structs (i.e. declared outside a function) are automatically zero initialized.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with these lines of code:

```
  CpuNode temp;
  temp= malloc(sizeof(CpuNode));
```

It should be

```
  CpuNode *temp;
  temp= (CpuNode *)malloc(sizeof(CpuNode));
```

Forgot the pointer in front of temp.

Here is the code that eliminated seg fault.

```
  inline static void push(List *q,CpuNode *n)
  {
    CpuNode *temp;                       

    temp= (CpuNode *)malloc(sizeof(CpuNode));
    temp->cpuid=n->cpuid;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if (q->HeadCpuNode==NULL) 
        q->HeadCpuNode=q->TailCpuNode=temp;
    else 
    {
       q->TailCpuNode=temp;  //This line should come first.
       q->TailCpuNode->next=temp;
    }   
}

void Discover(List *Acqcores)
{
    CpuNode *temp;
    temp= malloc(sizeof(CpuNode));
    temp->cpuid=1;
    push(Acqcores,temp);
}
```

Comment: sorry, I mistyped it. I have change that, still i am getting segmentation fault

Comment: Casting the return value of `malloc()` is an anachronism: the void pointer will be automatically promoted and the cast can mask an error. Unless you're using a pre-C89 compiler, it's neither necessary nor recommended.

Comment: Sorry but your are wrong. The problem is: `q->HeadCpuNode` which access an uninitialized member